# Style attribute for HTML elements in KotlinJS

Tags: html, kotlin, kotlin-js

I have the following HTML code that I would like to use in KotlinJS:

```
<div style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(84, 83, 97), rgb(25, 34, 99), rgb(49, 70, 180));" class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100"></div></div>
```

It adds `style` modifier to the `div` tag. Is there any way to provide `background` attribute to this style modifier?

The following code does not work:

```
 div("page-header align-items-start min-vh-100") {
                attrs.style = kotlinext.js.js {
                    background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(84, 83, 97), rgb(25, 34, 99), rgb(49, 70, 180));"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following hack: I added an ID and an attribute to the element

```
        document.getElementById("content-wrapper")?.setAttribute(
            "style",
            "BLABLA"
        )
```

But also this was fixed in Kotlin and now works in the following notation:

```
import kotlinx.js.jso 

style = jso {
  background = "BLABLA".unsafeCast<Color>()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [kotlin-styled](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-styled) or [kotlin-styled-next](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-styled-next).

Comment: Link-only answers and library recommendations are not considered good answers on SO.